# Change render resolution

Tags: rendering, orthographic, resolution

I am currently making some isometric sprites and I'm trying to get them to fit in a grid, but blender won't allow me to set the resolution to where I need it.

[image]

I'm trying to get the least amount of empty space around the mesh.

I'm also using an orthographic camera.

also if this is too confusing:

How get horizontal edges of camera to horizontal edges of mesh without vertical edges of camere go out and be all fucky

Comment: Perhaps the render border is the feature you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, this'll do fine.

Answer (score 0):

Changing resolution does not change the view size of the camera when in orthographic mode. You have to either change the size of the object you are looking at or change the ratio of your resolution.

Ex: 10,000 x 10,000 will be the same as 25 x 25 while in orthographic.